# NPM - Running npm i shows every single log in Source Control

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

Yesterday I was running into some issues with npm, namely a "can't find package.json file error. After some digging around, I ran

```
npm config set cache "C:\Users\(username)\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache" --global
```

which in the end didn't solve the issue, and now whenever I run a npm command in the terminal, [git logs every single file in Source Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkSV8.png)

So far, I've tried reinstalling node with different versions (14.15, 16.0) and deleting node-modules and running npm install again but to no avail. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Is the issue that you set the cache location to point to a directory where your git project also is?

Comment: I think that is where the issue lies. I guess I have to point the cache to where my project is?

Comment: No typically the cache location is some hidden away directory you never see and never have to think about.

Comment: So, should I set the directory of the cache back to where it was by default?

Comment: Fixed by setting the pathing of npm cache back to the npm-cache directory